# Update MySQL slave when changing the hostname/IP of master

Tags: mysql, replication

I have one master and one slave replicating great, but the master is about to have both it's hostname and IP changed. In `master.info` on the slave server I see the current hostname for the master, if I shutdown the slave server, change the hostname in that file and then restart MySQL will that be all I need? No usernames/passwords etc are changing.

If I used CHANGE MASTER queries instead it looks like it will require re-setting the binlog position etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you change the `MASTER_HOST`, everything else needs to change with it.

The "dark back-alley" approach you just suggested is exactly what to do.

```
Warning: Some systems use "mysqld" versus "mysql". 
The --skip-slave-restart "option" may not available without editing your
/etc/init.d/mysqld script to include this as a new option. 
If used, it will still start the slave upon startup.</p>
```

On the Slave, run these four lines:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql  
service mysql stop  
cp master.info master.info.bak
wc -l < master.info
```

The last line echoes the number of lines in `master.info`

Next, `vi master.info` and change the IP address.

Next, run `wc -l < master.info` and make sure the linecount is still the same

Next, start mysql without starting replication

```
service mysql start --skip-slave-start
```

Login to MySQL, and run

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

If the IP address you added appears, then run

```
START SLAVE; SELECT SLEEP(5);
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

If you see `Slave_IO_Running : Yes` and `Slave_SQL_Running : Yes`, Congratulations !!!

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Hey i was reading this http://linuxsysadminblog.com/2008/07/changing-the-mysql-replication-master-host/  

Why not doing it like this?

`STOP SLAVE;`
`SHOW SLAVE STATUS;`
`Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000101`
`Read_Master_Log_Pos: 591523680`
`CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='NEW IP ADDRESS', MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000101', MASTER_LOG_POS=591523680;
START SLAVE;`

Comment: FOR anyone trying to be lazy: `If you specify the MASTER_HOST or MASTER_PORT option, the slave assumes that the master server is different from before,  the old values for the master binary log file name and position are considered no longer applicable`